# Find all the children(GO IDs) for a given parent ID (GO ID) using Go ontology and R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I need to find all the children(GO IDs) under a parents (GO ID)  of [GO ontology (Go tree)](http://geneontology.org/page/ontology-structure).

Suppose, a GO ID = GO:0007114 (cell budding), Need to find all the children of it for all the labels.

Is there any R package or other way for finding the children based on GO Ontology for specific GO ID?

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/199968/

Comment: have you attempted anything?

Comment: I go for finding the children manually using the GO ontology file. But it is time consuming and the GO ontology file's format is not so much comfortable for parsing the file, it is complex